# Wordpress how to disable child pages for custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a `custom post type` called `designs`.

`designs` is registered like this:

```php
register_post_type(
  'Designs',
  theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'designs',
    'Design',
    'Designs',
    array(
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-appearance',
      'menu_position' => 20,
      'has_archive' => false,
      'public' => false,
      'supports' => array('title'),
    )
  )
);
```

For this post type, I don't want the following URLs to be accessible:

- `/designs`
- `/designs/post_name`

I'm just using this `post type` to extract data for a block, it's not a standard level one and level two layout.

From what I've seen online, `'has_archive'=> false` is what I need to achieve the above, however, it doesn't work for me? In the backend, the option to "view" a `design` post exists, which shouldn't be there as it shouldn't be generating a page for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this argument: `'publicly_queryable' => false` when you register your custom post type. It should do the trick for you!

From [`register_post_type`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#publicly_queryable):

> publicly_queryable:
> Whether queries can be performed on the front end as part of parse_request().
> If `false`, previewing/viewing of your custom post will return 404s.

```php
register_post_type(
  'Designs',
  theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'designs', 'Design', 'Designs',
    array(
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-appearance',
      'menu_position'=> 20,
      'has_archive'=> false,
      'public' => false,
      'publicly_queryable' => false,
      'supports'=> array('title'),
    )
  )
);
```

Let me know if you could get it to work!